# How did Ron find Harry in the pond?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

How did Ron get the Horcrux locket off Harry when they were in the lake/pond? How did he find them in the first place?

Comment: see [how-did-the-deluminator-help-ron-find-his-way-back](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12997/how-did-the-deluminator-help-ron-find-his-way-back)

Answer (score 14):

Ron found Harry and Hermione using the Deluminator. It released a ball of energy that *somehow* (insert plothole here) guided him to his friends' location.

> ‘So I took it out,’ Ron went on, looking at the Deluminator, ‘and it didn’t seem different, or anything, but I was sure I’d heard you. So I clicked it. And the light went out in my room, but another light appeared right outside the window.’
>
> Ron raised his empty hand and pointed in front of him, his eyes focused on something neither Harry nor Hermione could see.
>
> ‘It was a ball of light, kind of pulsing, and bluish, like that light you get around a Portkey, you know?’
>
> ‘Yeah,’ said Harry and Hermione together, automatically.
>
> ‘I knew this was it,’ said Ron. ‘I grabbed my stuff and packed it, then I put on my rucksack and went out into the garden.
>
> ‘The little ball of light was hovering there, waiting for me, and when I came out it bobbed along a bit and I followed it behind the shed and then it … well, it went inside me.’
>
> ‘Sorry?’ said Harry, sure he had not heard correctly.
>
> ‘It sort of floated towards me,’ said Ron, illustrating the movement with his free index finger, ‘right to my chest, and then – it just went straight through. It was here,’ he touched a point close to his heart, ‘I could feel it, it was hot. And once it was inside me I knew what I was supposed to do, I knew it would take me where I needed to go. So I Disapparated and came out on the side of a hill. There was snow everywhere …’
>
> ‘We were there,’ said Harry. ‘We spent two nights there, and the second night I kept thinking I could hear someone moving around in the dark and calling out!’
>
> ‘Yeah, well, that would’ve been me,’ said Ron. ‘Your protective spells work, anyway, because I couldn’t see you and I couldn’t hear you. I was sure you were around, though, so in the end I got in my sleeping bag and waited for one of you to appear. I thought you’d have to show yourselves when you packed up the tent.’

Once he found Harry, Ron swam down to collect the Sword of Gryffindor from the bottom of the lake and used it to cut the Horcrux off of Harry's neck.

> Nothing but the shock of hearing that voice could have given Harry the strength to get up. Shivering violently, he staggered to his feet.
>
> There before him stood Ron, fully dressed but drenched to the skin, his hair plastered to his face, the sword of Gryffindor in one hand and the Horcrux dangling from its broken chain in the other.
>
> *‘Why the hell,’ panted Ron, holding up the Horcrux, which swung backwards and forwards on its shortened chain in some parody of hypnosis, ‘didn’t you take this thing off before you dived?’
>
> *HP: DH*

Comment: *It released a ball of energy that somehow (insert plothole here) guided him to his friends' location.* - activate the plot device!

Comment: The plot here doesn't make sense, Ron just found his way as if by magic. Oh, wait...

Comment: I thought he had deluminated the lantern in their tent before leaving, or at least in the movies. So the light when released would fly back to its place at the tent.

Comment: @RobertGrant I fail to see how that's a plot hole. If that's the case then even worse would be the taboo curse breaking all protective enchantments. Just because it seems to contradict the normal situation doesn't equate it to a plot hole any more than something seeming quite obvious not being a plot hole. And in the end, as a worldbuilder, I can tell you that almost always magic can answer the otherwise impossible to answer questions; which is why you have to be careful setting up your rules first: Rowling covered those here and he didn't break their enchantments anyway so not a plot hole.

Answer (score 1):

The Deluminator that Dumbledore left him in his will. It started to transmit the words that Harry and Hermione were saying, and then a ball of light came out of it, and went inside him. So Ron Apparated to the forest, where he found Harry. Will add quotes later.

> "No, I heard you coming out of my pocket. Your voice," he held up the Deluminator again, "came out of this."
>
> ...
>
> "And the light went out in my room, but another light appeared right outside my window. ... It was a ball of light, kind of pulsing, and bluish, like that light you get around a Portkey, you know?"
>
> ‘Yeah,’ said Harry and Hermione together, automatically.
>
> ‘I knew this was it,’ said Ron. ‘I grabbed my stuff and packed it, then I put on my rucksack and went out into the garden.
>
> ‘The little ball of light was hovering there, waiting for me, and when I came out it bobbed along a bit and I followed it behind the shed and then it … well, it went inside me.’
>
> ‘Sorry?’ said Harry, sure he had not heard correctly.
>
> ‘It sort of floated towards me,’ said Ron, illustrating the movement with his free index finger, ‘right to my chest, and then – it just went straight through. It was here,’ he touched a point close to his heart, ‘I could feel it, it was hot. And once it was inside me I knew what I was supposed to do, I knew it would take me where I needed to go. So I Disapparated and came out on the side of a hill. There was snow everywhere …’

And he cut the Horcrux off of Harry with the Sword of Gryffindor. Later he stabbed the locket with the Sword, destroying it.